# Covariance between two random matrices

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

I have two random matrices (matrix-valued random variables) $X$ and $Y$, both of dimension $n \times n$. Is there a notion of covariance between the two random matrices, i.e., $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$? If yes, how can I calculate it?

Comment: By "random matrices" do you mean in the theoretical sense of matrix-valued random variables, or do you mean that each is an array of *realizations* of random variables? In the first sense your question cannot be answered except very generally (by quoting the definition) while in the second sense you simply haven't enough data.

Comment: You could vectorize (stack the columns of) each matrix and consider the covariance matrix between the two resulting vectors.

Comment: Hi Whuber, I actually mean matrix-valued random variable.

Answer (score 9):

The most common thing to do is probably to simply consider the covariance between the entries of the matrices. Defining $\DeclareMathOperator{\vec}{\mathrm{vec}}\vec(A)$ to be the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) of a matrix $A$ (that is, stack up the columns into a single column vector), you can look at $\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}\Cov(\vec(X), \vec(Y))$. This is then an $mn \times mn$ matrix.

If you preferred, you could instead define an $m \times n \times m \times n$ tensor, which would be essentially the same thing, just reshaped.

In e.g. the [matrix normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution), we assume that the covariance matrix of the single random matrix $X$ factors as the Kronecker product of an $m \times m$ row covariance $U$ and an $n \times n$ column covariance $V$, in which case you can often just work with $U$ or $V$.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I am assuming they are matrix-valued random variables. I changed my question a little bit, it should be two square matrices. So what about the expectation of a product of two matrix-valued random variables? If there is no correlation I am assuming that the expectation of the two matrices is just the product of the expectation of the two matrices? I am asking this question because in my case the two matrices can be correlated and I wonder how to calculate the expectation of the product. I am assuming that we need to calculate the covariance? Thanks!

Comment: @StellaLee To answer your comment-question in a comment (if it goes any further, you should ask this as a separate question): Note that $$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb E}\E[(X Y)_{ij}] = \E\left[\sum_k X_{ik} Y_{kj}\right] = \sum_k \E[X_{ik} Y_{kj}] = \sum_k \E[X_{ik}] \E[Y_{kj}] + \Cov(X_{ik}, Y_{kj}).$$ If you just want $\E[X Y]$, then doing it elementwise like this suffices, though if you want something like $\E[\lVert X Y \rVert]$ then it gets trickier.